# Is there a way to dynamically resize a Netty connection pool

Tags: netty

I am using Netty 4.0.37 and have a channel pool. Is there any way I can increase or shrink the pool size in run time ? Go from 5 to 20 back to 5 for example

Answer (score 0):

No... you will need to write your own `ChannelPool` implementation.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The interface channel pool has an acquire method in it, do you suggest i put in my resize logic there for my implementation? Since i am augmenting the pool with more connections, is there a "list" of connections in the pool that i need to add/take away my new channels?